# Is it acceptable to store the previous state as a global variable?

Tags: flex-lexer, lex, lexical-analysis

One of the biggest problems with designing a lexical analyzer/parser combination is overzealousness in designing the analyzer. (f)lex isn't designed to have parser logic, which can sometimes interfere with the design of mini-parsers (by means of `yy_push_state()`, `yy_pop_state()`, and `yy_top_state()`.

My goal is to parse a document of the form:

```
CODE1 this is the text that might appear for a 'CODE' entry
SUBCODE1 the CODE group will have several subcodes, which
      may extend onto subsequent lines.
SUBCODE2 however, not all SUBCODEs span multiple lines
SUBCODE3 still, however, there are some SUBCODES that span
      not only one or two lines, but any number of lines.
      this makes it a challenge to use something like \r\n
      as a record delimiter.
CODE2 Moreover, it's not guaranteed that a SUBCODE is the
      only way to exit another SUBCODE's scope. There may
      be CODE blocks that accomplish this.
```

In the end, I've decided that this section of the project is better left to the lexical analyzer, since I don't want to create a pattern that matches each line (and identifies continuation records). Part of the reason is that I want the lexical parser to have knowledge of the contents of each line, without incorporating its own tokenizing logic. That is to say, if I match `^SUBCODE[ ][ ].{71}\r\n` (all records are blocked in 80-character records) I would not be able to harness the power of flex to tokenize the structured data residing in `.{71}`.

Given these constraints, I'm thinking about doing the following:

1. Entering a `CODE1` state from the `<INITIAL>` start condition results
   in calls to:

   - `yy_push_state(CODE_STATE)`
   - `yy_push_state(CODE_CODE1_STATE)`
   - (do something with the contents of the `CODE1` state identifier, if such contents exist)
   - `yy_push_state(SUBCODE_STATE)` (to tell the analyzer to expect `SUBCODE` states belonging to the CODE_CODE1_STATE. **This is where the analyzer begins to masquerade as a parser.**
2. The `<SUBCODE1_STATE>` start condition is nested as follows: `<CODE_STATE>{ <CODE_CODE1_STATE> { <SUBCODE_STATE>{ <SUBCODE1_STATE> { (perform actions based on the matching patterns) } } }`. It also sets the global `previous_state` variable to `yy_top_state()`, to wit `SUBCODE1_STATE`.
3. Within `<SUBCODE1_STATE>`'s scope, `\r\n` will call `yy_pop_state()`. If a continuation record is present (which is a pattern at the highest scope against which all text is matched), `yy_push_state(continuation_record_states[previous_state])` is called, bringing us back to the scope in **2**. `continuation_record_states[]` maps each state with its continuation record state, which is used by the parser.

As you can see, this is quite complicated, which leads me to conclude that I'm massively over-complicating the task.

### Questions

1. For states lacking an extremely clear token signifying the end of its scope, is my proposed solution acceptable?
2. Given that I want to tokenize the input using flex, is there any way to do so without start conditions?

The biggest problem I'm having is that each record (beginning with the `(SUB)CODE` prefix) is unique, but the information appearing after the `(SUB)CODE` prefix is not. Therefore, it almost appears mandatory to have multiple states like this, and the abstract `CODE_STATE` and `SUBCODE_STATE` states would act as groupings for each of the concrete `SUBCODE[0-9]+_STATE` and `CODE[0-9]+_STATE` states.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at how the OMeta parser handles these things.